# Batch Combine two text files into one file, on top of each other

Tags: batch-file, text, vbscript

I'm having some trouble, this may seem a little weird. I'm working on a program to combine two files into one file, on the same lines. With only the differences showing. (Sorry for my bad explanation).
Therefore I would like to visualize it here:

```
File 1:

    ()
    []
    /\
--------------------------------------------------
```

Ander here is the other File:

```
File 2:

                                      ()
                                      []
                                      /\
--------------------------------------------------
```

I need these files to look like this, after running the script:

```
Combined Version:
    ()                                ()
    []                                []
    /\                                /\
--------------------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to find a way to combine the files, and replace already existing content, and only adding the new content.

I have tried several methods, I have tried to use the `FC` command, but I couldn't get that command to work. I tried to use commands like:

```
type "File 1.txt" 1>> Combined.txt
type "File 2.txt" 1>> Combined.txt
And I tried: for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> Combined.txt
```

Sadly, (as expected) none of this worked the way I wanted, the output of all my tries was the File 1 and File 2, in one file, but not combined, like this:

```
Combined Version:
    ()
    []
    /\
--------------------------------------------------

                                      ()
                                      []
                                      /\
--------------------------------------------------
```

And that is what I'm trying to avoid ;) So please, if you know anything to this topic, let me know. Also if you know any VBS Scripts to do this, please let me know too. :)

01/02/2018

**EDIT:**

Below I used **Squashman's** Script.. All my answers worked perfectly, sadly when I'm trying to use a longer line I get some errors.

```
File 1:
                 ()                                             
                 []                                             
                 /\                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

File 2:
                                           ()               
                                           []               
                                           /\                           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The result is this:

```
                                           ()                                    ()
                                           []                                    []
                                           /\                                    /\
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, the line clones itself. Another thing that I'm trying to do is to make a line standing, just like a 3rd character without a body. The result is sadly not what I expected. Let me visualize again :)

```
File 1:
                       ()                 !             
                       []                 !             
                       /\                 !                           
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

File 2:
                                          !              ()             
                                          !              []             
                                          !              /\           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And what I'm getting is a little weird. The result is here:

```
                       ()                 file2
                       []                 file2
                       /\                 file2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thank you.

After Changing ! with |:

```
                       ()                 |                                                       |              ()   
                       []                 |                                                       |              []   
                       /\                 |                                                                     |              /\
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

02/02/2018

Comment: You essentially need something similar to the Unix `paste` command.  So if you are willing to use a 3rd party utility you can get versions of the `paste` command for Windows.  It is available in the [UnixUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) package.

Comment: Thank for your answer below Squashman :). If it's possible I would like to stay with normal batch commands. Please check the rest of my answer below.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide new examples of your input.

Comment: Will do Squashman

Comment: replace the `!` with a `|` and test with my edited code. Any single `!` will be swallowed by delayed expansion.

Comment: The result is not as expected.. I updated it in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done due to the challenge. Note: this is quite slow because each character has to be processed on its own.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM read first file to array:
set i=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file1.txt) do (
  set /a i+=1
  set "file1-!i!=%%a"
)
REM read second file to array:
set i=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file2.txt) do (
  set /a i+=1
  set "file2-!i!=%%a"
)
REM calculate result
for /l %%i in (1,1,%i%) do (
  set "res="
  for /l %%j in (0,1,49) do call :join  %%i %%j
  >>file3.txt echo !res!
)
goto :eof

:join
set "f1=!file1-%1:~%2,1!"
set "f2=!file2-%1:~%2,1!"
if "%f1%" == "" set "f1= "
if "%f2%" == "" set "f2= "
if "%f2%" neq "%f1%" (
  if "%f2%" gtr " " (
    set "f3=%f2%"
  ) else (
    set "f3=%f1%"
  )
) else (
  set "f3=%f1%"
)
set "res=%res%%f3%"
goto :eof
```

file1.txt

```
    ()                  |
    qp                  |
    ||                  |
--------------------------------
```

file2.txt

```
                                      ()
                                      []
                                      /\
--------------------------------------------------
```

file3.txt

```
    ()                  |             ()
    qp                  |             []
    ||                  |             /\
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: don't accept this answer too early. I'm quite sure, @dbenham will come up with a nice one-liner using `jrepl.bat`

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, it's really appreciated. I can wait to mark it as correct answer :). But before that, I got a question, if my line, the characters stands on is longer than the line specified above, it wont display it. Is there any way to fix that or change it?

Comment: @MortenOrum: fixed.

Comment: There may be an error, the output I'm getting, is a display of one of the two files, with a lot of numbers. And it crashes instantly. I can only see one of the two characters. Tried changing ! and |, still no success

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think I understand, what you're trying to do. I have my file 1 and file 2 with the same stuff, the only difference is where the character is. When I try to run your code, I'm getting a picture of the file 1, with a smaller line, and the three |||. Not sure why :/

Comment: If you could explain, how my files need to be written to work, that would be perfect. ;)

Comment: works fine for me (see output). Have you changed the code? Do the files have the correct coding (ANSI)?

Comment: Okay, so I know this is old.. I'm very sorry.. ;) I figured it out, I don't know what I did last time, but it's working perfect now. Thanks again. -Morten

Answer (score 0):

This is something close to what you want with a batch file.  The only problem is the the last line is very long because it merges the lines together.  The paste command would do the same thing.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
< file2.txt ( FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (file1.txt) DO (
set /p file2=
echo %%G!file2!
)
)>combined.txt
type combined.txt
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can clearly see what you mean :) Are there any possibility to change how the lines merges? Also, if I remove the lines and make the characters stand, longer away from each other, it comes up with "file2""file2""file2" Any way to fix that? Btw. Your answer is appreciated ;)